# How to increment a number within a variable name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript for loop:

```
for (var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
   $(".afterglowplayer"+i).click(function () {$.afterglowplayer+i.toggle(this); return false;});
}
```

I need to increment the number at the end of a jQuery variable name so that I get this:

```
$.afterglowplayer1.toggle(this);
$.afterglowplayer2.toggle(this);
```

I have tried using

```
$.afterglowplayer+i.toggle(this);
```

and

```
$.afterglowplayer+"+i+".toggle(this);
```

But it is not correct way... is it possible to increment the number at the end of a jQuery variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [JavaScript closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```javascript
for (var i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
  (function(n) {
    $('.afterglowplayer'+n).click(function () {
      $('.afterglowplayer'+n).toggle(this); return false;
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `let` keyword

```js
for (let i=1; i <= 2; i++) {
   $(".afterglowplayer"+i).click(function () {
      $('.afterglowplayer'+i).toggle(this);
      return false;
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='afterglowplayer1'>Foo</div>
<div class='afterglowplayer2'>Bar</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$['afterglowplayer'+i].toggle(this);
```